# How to access public methods from another Windows Phone page

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

Is there an shorter way to access public methods from other windows phone pages (e.g. from the `MainPage.xaml`) then this?

```
((MainPage)(((System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)(App.RootFrame)).Content)).getMyPublicMethod()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I can see that's the only way. But you can create a wrapper to shorten syntax to access that page. For example, method wrapper :

```
public MainPage getMainPage()
{
    return (MainPage)(((System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)(App.RootFrame)).Content);
}

//usage :
getMainPage().getMyPublicMethod();
```

or property wrapper :

```
public MainPage OtherWindow
{
    return (MainPage)(((System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)(App.RootFrame)).Content);
}

//usage :
OtherWindow.getMyPublicMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing it the way you are, you have a **very bad** separation of concerns. Normally, the view (aka the `Page` in this case) should not carry any functional components in terms of triggering actions that might be needed in another view.

A much better solution is to use the 'light' [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) approach, where you have a core view model and then simply call actions from it, passing the necessary data from view to view. I've described a basic implementation [here](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/simple-binding-simple-maybe).